# hide popover when textbox is valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am using bootstrap popover to display if password is less then 6 character.
It works fine but when I click in text it display popover even value of text box is valid. how to hide popover when length of text box is valid

```
<head>
   <title>popover example</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>   



</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

<h1>Bootstrap popover Example</h1>

<div>

<input type="password" id="password1" placeholder="password" data-toggle="popover" >

</div>

</div>
```

Here is my js code I remove div with popover when length is valid . But problem is text box displays popup when I click in text . I want to display popover only when length is less then 6 .

```
<script>


   $(function ()
      {
      debugger;
        $('#password1').blur(function(){
         debugger;
            if($('#password1').val().length<6){
                $("#password1").popover({
                    title:"test",
                    content:"Must be 6 characters long! Must contain a capital letter"
                }); 
                $("#password1").popover('show');
            }else{
            $("#password1").parent().removeClass('popover');
            }
        });
    })();



   </script>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .popover('destroy') instead of .popover('hide') since if you click again on the textbox, it will keep showing you again even if the characters are more than 6.

```js
$(function() {
  debugger;
  $('#password1').blur(function() {
    debugger;
    if ($('#password1').val().length < 6) {
      $("#password1").popover({
        title: "test",
        content: "Must be 6 characters long! Must contain a capital letter"
      });
      $("#password1").popover('show');
    } else {
      $("#password1").popover('destroy');
    }
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <h1>Bootstrap popover Example</h1>

  <div>

    <input type="password" id="password1" placeholder="password">

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the *hide* function of popover

```
    $("#password1").popover('hide')
```

Comment: Reference to my intuition

Comment: its not working it display popover again when i click in text box

Answer (score 1):

> Please check this

```
   $(function ()
   {
   debugger;
     $('#password1').blur(function(){
      debugger;      
         if($('#password1').val().length<6){
             $("#password1").popover({
                 title:"test",
                 content:"Must be 6 characters long! Must contain a capital letter"
             }); 
             $("#password1").popover('show');
         }else{
             $("#password1").popover('destroy');
         }
     });
     $('#password1').click(function(){
         if($('#password1').val().length>5){  
             $("#password1").popover('destroy');
         }
     });
 })();
```